# Sencha CMD generate app with specific version

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

I need to generate an ExtJS app version 5.1.1, but when I run the command `sencha generate app -ext AppName .`, it will automatically download the latest version of the framework, which is 6.0 right now.

How can I force it to generate an ExtJS 5.1.1 app?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify path to whatever framework you want to use:

```
sencha -sdk path/to/extjs5.1.1 generate app AppName path/to/appname
```

If you have previously used ExtJS 5.1.1 with your Sencha CMD installation, it would still be residing in the local repo. In my case (Ubuntu 14.04) the location is: `~/bin/Sencha/Cmd/repo/extract/ext/5.1.1.451`.

Alternatively, you can download and extract GPL version from [official CDN](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/ext-5.1.1-gpl.zip).

Note: using Sencha CMD 6 with ExtJS 5 may be a bit troublesome — I had some glitches with `neptune-touch` theme which did not occur when using CMD5 with ExtJS5 or CMD6 with ExtJS6.

Answer (score 0):

I already had an application, but it did not contain the ExtJS framework as we are not commiting it in our SVN repositories.

While this does not answers specifically *this* question, it solved my problem:

All I needed to do was run `sencha app build` inside my project's folder so it will automatically download the correct framework version specified in the project's configuration files, whether it is the most current version or not.